# Remove everything jack related

Tags: arch-linux, pulseaudio, jack

I made the stupid mistake to install jack2 while using pulseaudio. The audio wasn't working at all (and I realized I didn't need Jack) so I decided to remove jack2. Now I do have sound (with the laptop's built in speakers), but pavucontrol is not loading (frozen at Establishing connection with pulseaudio. Please wait..." and I get this when I run "pulseaudio"

```
~>$ pulseaudio 
E: [pulseaudio] ltdl-bind-now.c: Failed to open module module-jack-sink.so: module-jack-sink.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
E: [pulseaudio] module.c: Failed to open module "module-jack-sink".
E: [pulseaudio] main.c: Module load failed.
E: [pulseaudio] main.c: Failed to initialize daemon.
```

How can I remove all that depends from jack? I want to run plain pulseaudio.

I'm using arch linux

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to solve it removing all local config files from ~/.config/pulse and ~/.pulse
Now it works perfectly

Answer (score 1):

It looks like pulseaudio still tries to load the jack module. Check if you have pulseaudio-jack installed and remove it if appropriate. The default pulseaudio config that Arch ships with will try to load the module if it is installed, check /etc/pulse/default.pa and /etc/pulse/system.pa for "load-module". Note that if you use mpv or mplayer or a lot of related software, these packages will actually depend on jack (not jack2), so in this case you'll additionally need to reinstall jack (which conflicts with jack2).